# How to Make Checkbox Visible Based on Selected Dropdown Item

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to get a checkbox and its related label (in the "addfiles" span) to appear only when drop down item 3 (attach files) is selected. The addfiles span will be hidden when its not selected.

I'm new to jQuery and I don't know where to begin to do this.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>

  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form name="frmChkForm" id="frmChkForm">
      <select name="service" id="service" class="required contact-service">
        <option value="">Select Option</option>
        <option value="1">feedback</option>
        <option value="2">updates</option>
        <option value="3">attach files</option>
      </select>

      <p>
        <span id="addfiles">
          <input type="checkbox" name="attachfiles" id="attachfiles" value="yes">Attach files    
        </span>
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nobody is going to code it for you. Try your code and if it doesn't work, make a jsfiddle out of it and paste it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) for the dropdown selection change.

`this.value` inside the `.change()` event should get the current selected value.

[strict equal to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity) operator can be used for the value comparison

[.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) will show your hidden element

```
$(function()
{
    $("#service").change(function(){
        if(this.value === 3) {
            $("#addfiles").show();
        } else {
            $("#addfiles").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

You can have a detailed read in [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#addfiles').hide()
       $('#frmChkForm').change(function(){
          var selectedOption = $(this).val()
          if(selectedOption == 3){
              $('#addfiles').fadeIn()
          }else{
             $('#addfiles').fadeOut()
          }
       })
    })
```